# How to build FAQ knowledgebase app integrated to my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am building a FAQ knowledgebase for my rails application

1. Contains several topics
2. Contains several sub-topics
3. Contains questions/answers under each of the above topics
4. Ability to add a question
5. Search questions by a keyword

Is there a out-of-the-box gem or an app which I can integrate with. I don't want to build a home grown solution and prefer something external

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mount [how_to](https://github.com/railscash/how_to) gem to your existing application. Only search is missing in this gem. Here is [demo](http://how-to-demo.herokuapp.com/how_to/)

Comment: Is there any other Gem to implement FAQ on the UI ?